# android how to change the starting activity

Tags: java, android

I have built an application with one activity for android. I now want to add a LOGIN page which should be run first. how can I change the application to run login first?

my first activity was MainActivity.java. I went to the application's properties -> run/debug settings -> edit conf. -> Launch action. But there is only Mainactivity, I cannot see Login activity.

I am using Eclipse, by the way.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: have you taken a look of android manifest? Have a look around

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look at the manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YOUR_LOGIN_ACTIVITY"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and modify entry of MainActivity as

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
```

---

***Update***

You should read [Declaring the activity in the manifest and use of intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) for more. [Search for 'Using intent filters']

Answer (score 1):

Inside your AndroidManifest change following line: android:name="com.example.webviewdemo.MainActivity" put your login Activity with including package name like com.example.login.LoginActivity.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webviewdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.webviewdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```